# Odoo: How to get the company infos in qweb report?

Tags: odoo-8

How can i get the company infos in qweb report? 
I have added

```
<t t-call="report.external_layout">
   --------------
   --------------
   <span t-field="company.partner_id.street"/>
</t>
```

to my report but i get  this error

QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partner_id'" while evaluating
'company.partner_id'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all the company information like the following

```
<span t-esc="o.company_id.name"/>
<span t-esc="o.company_id.street"/>
<span t-esc="o.company_id.city"/>
<span t-esc="o.company_id.state_id.name"/>
<span t-esc="o.company_id.zip"/>
```

OR

```
<span t-field="res_company.partner_id.name"/>
<span t-field="res_company.partner_id.street"/>
<span t-field="res_company.partner_id.city"/>
```